# Seaborn Scatter plot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset containing of only one column, using matplotlib I was able to do the scatter plot the following way

```
data = pd.read_csv
plt.scatter(data.index,data.coulumn1)
```

I want the same graph using seaborn but I am not sure how to implement the same approach in the following line

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
```

With this format, Seaborn support Pandas DataFrame.
`"total_bill"` and `"tip"` are the name of the columns. `"tips"` is the `pd.DataFrame`.

You can plot on default Axis by

```
sns.scatterplot(x="X_Colname", y="Y_Colname", data=DataFrame)

#Can also pass the desired Axis to customize size etc.
sns.scatterplot(x="X_Colname", y="Y_Colname", data=DataFrame, ax=ax)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use same approach for seaborn which you have been using for matplotlib. Both works exactly same way.

```
plt.scatter(data.index, data.coulumn1)
sns.scatterplot(data.index, data.coulumn1)
```

Both will display same graph.